# angularJS - multiple browser tabs/windows one JSESSIONID?

Tags: angularjs

i have an angularJS which you start like this:

```
> http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/test/864/38383838383
```

last number is a token which authenticates the user. it works fine. if i start my app with a valid token, i geht a cookie/JSESSIONID from the server which i can use for my other http requests. if the user starts the app again with the same token, you get an error because the token is invalid. also ok. my question now is ... if i start the app with an valid token and i get an JSESSIONID ... and if i start the app again with the same token in a second browser tab/window ... is it possible to check/get the JSESSIONID from the other tap/window without making the authentication-process again?

best regards

Comment: Also of interest: why would you want to do that?

Comment: because it is possible that the user klicks more than one time on that link so the second klick ends on an error. AND i also load some properties on the first start of the app. perhaps it is also possible to load this only on time and use it on the other windows/tabs.

Comment: if you just want to access the SessionID from the other tab, isnt storing and accessing from cookie helping? Using javascript I dont think its possible to talk to other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the JSESSIONID from URI and store it in a cookie. Browser will send all the cookies set for a domain with each request, so your server code will know that it is the same session.
You do not have to do anything AngularJS-specific for this to work. Just configure session tracking mode to COOKIE in your server-side code.

Comment: how can i get (the value form) JSESSIONID?

Comment: You should look into session object that your framework provides. 
I believe that for most Java frameworks it is returned by `session.getId()` method.
The session should be available via current context.

Comment: "The session should be available via current context" -> not it isn't ... any other idea?